# Validation Error saying path required while sending POST request in MongoDB through node express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

While sending POST request I am getting few strange response though my code is same as what has shown here.

1. If I keep required :true then in POST request I am getting PATH require validation error of schema
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCqAw.png)
2. If comment all those line where I have written required: true then It won't accept my post request 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0HKN.png)rather It store a default value in document,

Can anyone help me in this case? I got stuck with it for a long time.

Comment: I think you are using mongoose, can you show your Dish schema

Comment: please post the code